# Abort installation in restartless addon

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

The addon I'm working on requires another addon to be present for it to work. During installation, if that required addon isnt present, it shows the user an alert message. I'm wondering if I can also abort the installation at that point?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot abort the installation of add-ons.

What you can do, however, is upon start up you can check for some condition (like "add-on xzy installed?") and if it is not met disable and/or uninstall your add-on again automatically.

Get your own add-on instance via [`AddonManager.getAddonByID()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager#getAddonByID%28%29) and either set `.userDisabled = true` on the returned (via callback) [`Addon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/Addon?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Addons%2FAdd-on_Manager%2FAddon) instance or call `Addon.uninstall()`.

Load the `AddonManager` using [`chrome`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Chrome_authority) via `Cu.import()`.

I wouldn't recommend to uninstall the add-on without explicit user consent. The user might want to install the dependency and then just re-enable your add-on, which he can't when you uninstall. Hence it would be better to just disable the add-on.